# Why the ActionListener does not work?

Tags: java, swing

I have been trying to make this and it does work, except that when i click the button nothing happens, it's for a college project.

All i need to know is how to make the button work as intended, to make the functions im coding it to do.

```
 /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package proyecto;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;



/**
 *
 * @author Cristian
 */
public class Diseños extends JComponent implements ActionListener {

   JButton Boton1, Boton2, Boton3, Boton4, Boton5, Boton6, Boton7;





  @Override
  public void paint(Graphics g) {    


    this.Boton1=new JButton("-"); 
    this.Boton1.setBounds(90, 410, 30, 30); 
    this.Boton1.setBackground(Color.black);
    Component agregar1 = add(Boton1);



    this.Boton2=new JButton("-"); 
    this.Boton2.setBounds(150, 410, 30, 30); 
    this.Boton2.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    Component agregar2 = add(Boton2);

    this.Boton3 =new JButton("-"); 
    this.Boton3.setBounds(210, 410, 30, 30); 
    this.Boton3.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    Component agregar3 = add(Boton3);

    this.Boton4=new JButton("-"); 
    this.Boton4.setBounds(270, 410, 30, 30); 
    this.Boton4.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    Component agregar4 = add(Boton4);

    this.Boton5=new JButton("-"); 
    this.Boton5.setBounds(330, 410, 30, 30); 
    this.Boton5.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    Component agregar5 = add(Boton5);

    this.Boton6=new JButton("-"); 
    this.Boton6.setBounds(390, 410, 30, 30); 
    this.Boton6.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    Component agregar6 = add(Boton6);

    this.Boton7=new JButton("-"); 
    this.Boton7.setBounds(450, 410, 30, 30); 
    this.Boton7.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    Component agregar7 = add(Boton7);

    g.drawRect (570, 10, 300, 200);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(570, 10, 300, 200);
    g.drawRect (570, 250, 300, 200);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(570, 250, 300, 200);
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    Font oldFont=getFont();
    Font fuente=new Font("Primer Jugador", Font.BOLD, 14);
    g.setFont(fuente);
    g.drawString("Primer Jugador", 580, 30);
    Font titulo=new Font("Segundo Jugador", Font.BOLD, 14);
    g.setFont(titulo);
    g.drawString("Segundo Jugador", 580, 270);
    g.drawString("[ " + Proyecto.primernombre + " ]", 580, 50);
    g.drawString("[ " + Proyecto.segundonombre + " ]", 580, 290);
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.fillRoundRect(10, 5, 550, 450, 50, 50);
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.fillOval(80, 50, 50, 50);
    g.fillOval(140, 50, 50, 50);
    g.fillOval(200, 50, 50, 50);
    g.fillOval(260, 50, 50, 50);
    g.fillOval(320, 50, 50, 50);
    g.fillOval(380, 50, 50, 50);
    g.fillOval(440, 50, 50, 50);
    g.fillOval(80, 110, 50, 50);
    g.fillOval(140, 110, 50, 50);
    g.fillOval(200, 110, 50, 50);
    g.fillOval(260, 110, 50, 50);
    g.fillOval(320, 110, 50, 50);
    g.fillOval(380, 110, 50, 50);
    g.fillOval(440, 110, 50, 50);
    g.fillOval(80, 170, 50, 50);
    g.fillOval(140, 170, 50, 50);
    g.fillOval(200, 170, 50, 50);
    g.fillOval(260, 170, 50, 50);
    g.fillOval(320, 170, 50, 50);
    g.fillOval(380, 170, 50, 50);
    g.fillOval(440, 170, 50, 50);
    g.fillOval(80, 230, 50, 50);
    g.fillOval(140, 230, 50, 50);
    g.fillOval(200, 230, 50, 50);
    g.fillOval(260, 230, 50, 50);
    g.fillOval(320, 230, 50, 50);
    g.fillOval(380, 230, 50, 50);
    g.fillOval(440, 230, 50, 50);
    g.fillOval(80, 290, 50, 50);
    g.fillOval(140, 290, 50, 50);
    g.fillOval(200, 290, 50, 50);
    g.fillOval(260, 290, 50, 50);
    g.fillOval(320, 290, 50, 50);
    g.fillOval(380, 290, 50, 50);
    g.fillOval(440, 290, 50, 50);
    g.fillOval(80, 350, 50, 50);
    g.fillOval(140, 350, 50, 50);
    g.fillOval(200, 350, 50, 50);
    g.fillOval(260, 350, 50, 50);
    g.fillOval(320, 350, 50, 50);
    g.fillOval(380, 350, 50, 50);
    g.fillOval(440, 350, 50, 50);
}

    @Override
     public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent ae){       
        if(ae.getSource().equals(Boton1) && turno.Tjugador == true && colores.colorjugador[0] == 1 && matrices.matrizraya[0] == 6) {
            System.out.println("I doubt this is even working");
            turno.Tjugador = false;
            matrices.matrizraya[0] --;           
            getGraphics().setColor(Color.RED);
            getGraphics().fillOval(80, 350, 50, 50);
            repaint();
        }

    }
}
```

Edit : I've been retesting and the code works but only when i don't use if, why is this ?

Edit : Ok i solved the button problem but i got a new one, when i try to change the background color of Boton61 i get this error :

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at proyecto.Diseños.actionPerformed(Diseños.java:364)

```
package proyecto;


import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;



/**
 *
 * @author Cristian
 *
 * */

public class Diseños extends JComponent implements ActionListener {

   JButton Boton1, Boton2, Boton3, Boton4, Boton5, Boton6, Boton7;

   JButton Boton11,Boton21,Boton31,Boton41,Boton51,Boton61;
   JButton Boton12,Boton22,Boton32,Boton42,Boton52,Boton62;
   JButton Boton13,Boton23,Boton33,Boton43,Boton53,Boton63;
   JButton Boton14,Boton24,Boton34,Boton44,Boton54,Boton64;
   JButton Boton15,Boton25,Boton35,Boton45,Boton55,Boton65;
   JButton Boton16,Boton26,Boton36,Boton46,Boton56,Boton66;
   JButton Boton17,Boton27,Boton37,Boton47,Boton57,Boton67;




   @Override
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {    
     Boton1=new JButton("lol"); 
    Boton1.setBounds(90, 410, 30, 30); 
    Boton1.setBackground(Color.black);
    Component agregar1 = add(Boton1);
    Boton1.addActionListener(new Diseños());


    Boton2=new JButton("lol"); 
    Boton2.setBounds(150, 410, 30, 30); 
    Boton2.setBackground(Color.black);
    Component agregar2 = add(Boton2);
    Boton2.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton3=new JButton("lol"); 
    Boton3.setBounds(210, 410, 30, 30); 
    Boton3.setBackground(Color.black);
    Component agregar3 = add(Boton3);
    Boton3.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton4=new JButton("lol"); 
    Boton4.setBounds(270, 410, 30, 30); 
    Boton4.setBackground(Color.black);
    Component agregar4 = add(Boton4);
    Boton4.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton5=new JButton("lol"); 
    Boton5.setBounds(330, 410, 30, 30); 
    Boton5.setBackground(Color.black);
    Component agregar5 = add(Boton5);
    Boton5.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton6=new JButton("lol"); 
    Boton6.setBounds(390, 410, 30, 30); 
    Boton6.setBackground(Color.black);
    Component agregar6 = add(Boton6);
    Boton6.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton7=new JButton("lol"); 
    Boton7.setBounds(450, 410, 30, 30); 
    Boton7.setBackground(Color.black);
    Component agregar7 = add(Boton7);
    Boton7.addActionListener(new Diseños());


    Boton11=new JButton(""); 
    Boton11.setBounds(85, 10, 40, 60); 
    Boton11.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar11 = add(Boton11);
    Boton11.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton21=new JButton(""); 
    Boton21.setBounds(85, 70, 40, 60); 
    Boton21.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar21 = add(Boton21);
    Boton21.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton31=new JButton(""); 
    Boton31.setBounds(85, 130, 40, 60); 
    Boton31.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar31 = add(Boton31);
    Boton31.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton41=new JButton(""); 
    Boton41.setBounds(85, 190, 40, 60); 
    Boton41.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar41 = add(Boton41);
    Boton41.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton51=new JButton(""); 
    Boton51.setBounds(85, 250, 40, 60); 
    Boton51.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar51 = add(Boton51);
    Boton51.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton61=new JButton(""); 
    Boton61.setBounds(85, 310, 40, 60); 
    Boton61.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar61 = add(Boton61);
    Boton61.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton12=new JButton(""); 
    Boton12.setBounds(145, 10, 40, 60); 
    Boton12.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar12 = add(Boton12);
    Boton12.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton22=new JButton(""); 
    Boton22.setBounds(145, 70, 40, 60); 
    Boton22.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar22 = add(Boton22);
    Boton22.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton32=new JButton(""); 
    Boton32.setBounds(145, 130, 40, 60); 
    Boton32.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar32 = add(Boton32);
    Boton32.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton42=new JButton(""); 
    Boton42.setBounds(145, 190, 40, 60); 
    Boton42.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar42 = add(Boton42);
    Boton42.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton52=new JButton(""); 
    Boton52.setBounds(145, 250, 40, 60); 
    Boton52.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar52 = add(Boton52);
    Boton52.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton62=new JButton(""); 
    Boton62.setBounds(145, 310, 40, 60); 
    Boton62.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar62 = add(Boton62);
    Boton62.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton13=new JButton(""); 
    Boton13.setBounds(205, 10, 40, 60); 
    Boton13.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar13 = add(Boton13);
    Boton13.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton23=new JButton(""); 
    Boton23.setBounds(205, 70, 40, 60); 
    Boton23.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar23 = add(Boton23);
    Boton23.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton33=new JButton(""); 
    Boton33.setBounds(205, 130, 40, 60); 
    Boton33.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar33 = add(Boton33);
    Boton33.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton43=new JButton(""); 
    Boton43.setBounds(205, 190, 40, 60); 
    Boton43.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar43 = add(Boton43);
    Boton43.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton53=new JButton(""); 
    Boton53.setBounds(205, 250, 40, 60); 
    Boton53.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar53 = add(Boton53);
    Boton53.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton63=new JButton(""); 
    Boton63.setBounds(205, 310, 40, 60); 
    Boton63.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar63 = add(Boton63);
    Boton63.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton14=new JButton(""); 
    Boton14.setBounds(265, 10, 40, 60); 
    Boton14.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar14 = add(Boton14);
    Boton14.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton24=new JButton(""); 
    Boton24.setBounds(265, 70, 40, 60); 
    Boton24.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar24 = add(Boton24);
    Boton24.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton34=new JButton(""); 
    Boton34.setBounds(265, 130, 40, 60); 
    Boton34.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar34 = add(Boton34);
    Boton34.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton44=new JButton(""); 
    Boton44.setBounds(265, 190, 40, 60); 
    Boton44.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar44 = add(Boton44);
    Boton44.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton54=new JButton(""); 
    Boton54.setBounds(265, 250, 40, 60); 
    Boton54.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar54 = add(Boton54);
    Boton54.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton64=new JButton(""); 
    Boton64.setBounds(265, 310, 40, 60); 
    Boton64.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar64 = add(Boton64);
    Boton64.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton15=new JButton(""); 
    Boton15.setBounds(325, 10, 40, 60); 
    Boton15.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar15 = add(Boton15);
    Boton15.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton25=new JButton(""); 
    Boton25.setBounds(325, 70, 40, 60); 
    Boton25.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar25 = add(Boton25);
    Boton25.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton35=new JButton(""); 
    Boton35.setBounds(325, 130, 40, 60); 
    Boton35.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar35 = add(Boton35);
    Boton35.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton45=new JButton(""); 
    Boton45.setBounds(325, 190, 40, 60); 
    Boton45.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar45 = add(Boton45);
    Boton45.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton55=new JButton(""); 
    Boton55.setBounds(325, 250, 40, 60); 
    Boton55.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar55 = add(Boton55);
    Boton55.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton65=new JButton(""); 
    Boton65.setBounds(325, 310, 40, 60); 
    Boton65.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar65 = add(Boton65);
    Boton65.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton16=new JButton(""); 
    Boton16.setBounds(385, 10, 40, 60); 
    Boton16.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar16 = add(Boton16);
    Boton16.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton26=new JButton(""); 
    Boton26.setBounds(385, 70, 40, 60); 
    Boton26.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar26 = add(Boton26);
    Boton26.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton36=new JButton(""); 
    Boton36.setBounds(385, 130, 40, 60); 
    Boton36.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar36 = add(Boton36);
    Boton36.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton46=new JButton(""); 
    Boton46.setBounds(385, 190, 40, 60); 
    Boton46.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar46 = add(Boton46);
    Boton46.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton56=new JButton(""); 
    Boton56.setBounds(385, 250, 40, 60); 
    Boton56.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar56 = add(Boton56);
    Boton56.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton66=new JButton(""); 
    Boton66.setBounds(385, 310, 40, 60); 
    Boton66.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar66 = add(Boton66);
    Boton66.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton17=new JButton(""); 
    Boton17.setBounds(445, 10, 40, 60); 
    Boton17.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar17 = add(Boton17);
    Boton17.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton27=new JButton(""); 
    Boton27.setBounds(445, 70, 40, 60); 
    Boton27.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar27 = add(Boton27);
    Boton27.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton37=new JButton(""); 
    Boton37.setBounds(445, 130, 40, 60); 
    Boton37.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar37 = add(Boton37);
    Boton37.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton47=new JButton(""); 
    Boton47.setBounds(445, 190, 40, 60); 
    Boton47.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar47 = add(Boton47);
    Boton47.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton57=new JButton(""); 
    Boton57.setBounds(445, 250, 40, 60); 
    Boton57.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar57 = add(Boton57);
    Boton57.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton67=new JButton(""); 
    Boton67.setBounds(445, 310, 40, 60); 
    Boton67.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar67 = add(Boton67);
    Boton67.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawRect (570, 10, 300, 200);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(570, 10, 300, 200);
    g.drawRect (570, 250, 300, 200);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(570, 250, 300, 200);
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    Font oldFont=getFont();
    Font fuente=new Font("Primer Jugador", Font.BOLD, 14);
    g.setFont(fuente);
    g.drawString("Primer Jugador", 580, 30);
    Font titulo=new Font("Segundo Jugador", Font.BOLD, 14);
    g.setFont(titulo);
    g.drawString("Segundo Jugador", 580, 270);
    g.drawString("[ " + Proyecto.primernombre + " ]", 580, 50);
    g.drawString("[ " + Proyecto.segundonombre + " ]", 580, 290);
    g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
    g.fillRoundRect(10, 5, 550, 450, 50, 50);
  }


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        System.out.println("Ayy lmao");
        Boton61.setBackground(Color.blue);
        Boton61.repaint();
    }
}


            Line 364 is :

Boton61.setBackground(Color.blue);
```

Comment: Note you state, `"I have been trying to make this and it does work, except that when i click the button nothing happens, it's for a college project. All i need to know is how to make the button work as intended, to make the functions im coding it to do."`, but you haven't told us what the button should be doing that it's not currently doing. Please consider providing more information so we can give more complete and helpful answers.

Comment: If all the conditions are met, the code is supposed to repaint the oval from white to red in the first column.

Comment: What conditions and which oval?

Comment: Also, what game is it you're creating? Is it [Connect Four](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connect_Four)?

Comment: Yes, it's connect four.

Comment: `"Edit : I've been retesting and the code works but only when i don't use if, why is this ?"` -- you need to show us this updated code, the code where you don't add components in a painting method and where you actually add ActionListeners to buttons...

Comment: I've got a new problem now, which is that error shown above in line 364.

Comment: A new problem means you should mark this question **solved** by accepting the most helpful answer, and then post a new question on this site with your code and question. By the way, consider commenting on whether the answers helped you or not. Silence == being ignored and that's never good, especially if effort was expended trying to help you. At least up-vote the answers that helped you, even just a little bit.

Comment: By the way, learn to use for loops and arrays, and (again) to use layout managers. Doing so will simplify your code greatly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suggestions:

- Add the ActionListener to the button. Here that would mean `Boton3.addActionListener(this);`.
- You should not be creating components or adding them to the GUI in any painting method. Painting methods such as paint or paintComponent should be for painting and painting only.

  - You do not have direct control over when or even **if** a painting method will be called, nor can you control how many times it will be called, and so this makes it a dangerous place to use for changing a GUI's components.
  - Anything that slows painting down will make your GUI seem less responsive, which will not be appreciated by the user. For this reason, painting methods should strive to be lean and **fast**, and again should be involved with painting **only**.
- You will want to not override a JComponent's paint method but rather its paintComponent method.
- Don't call `getGraphics()` on a component nor try to draw with a Graphics object thus obtained. Doing this will give you a short-lived Graphics object which will make your drawing unstable. Instead do your all of your drawing within a paintComponent method using the Graphics object given to you by the JVM.
- You can get around the above restriction by calling `getGraphics()` on a BufferedImage and drawing within *that*, but you will still need to draw the BufferedImage within your paintComponent method via the `g.drawImage(...)` method.
- Myself, I'd do things differently including creating a JPanel that uses a GridLayout that holds JLabels with circle ImageIcons on them and at the bottom a JButton. Then when the button was pressed, I'd swap ImageIcons in the JLabel that needed swapping. It would be much easier to maintain and enhance this since there would be no hard-coding of locations.

---

For example, you could even potentially do away with the column JButtons and instead use a grid of JLabels, giving them a MouseListener that checks what column the JLabel is in, and then that adds a colored disk depending on the column pressed:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Connect4Panel extends JPanel {
   public static final int ROWS = 6;
   public static final int COLUMNS = 7;
   public static final int DISK_WIDTH = 50;
   public static final int DISK_BORDER_WIDTH = 5;
   private static final Color FIRST_COLOR = Color.red;
   private static final Color SECOND_COLOR = Color.black;
   private Icon emptyIcon;
   private Icon firstIcon;
   private Icon secondIcon;
   private JLabel[][] diskGrid = new JLabel[ROWS][COLUMNS];
   private boolean firstTurn = true;

   public Connect4Panel() {
      emptyIcon = createIcons(new Color(0, 0, 0, 15));
      firstIcon = createIcons(FIRST_COLOR);
      secondIcon = createIcons(SECOND_COLOR);

      DiskListener diskListener = new DiskListener();
      // setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
      setLayout(new GridLayout(ROWS, COLUMNS, 2, 0));
      for (int row = 0; row < diskGrid.length; row++) {
         for (int col = 0; col < diskGrid[row].length; col++) {
            JLabel disk = new JLabel(emptyIcon);
            disk.addMouseListener(diskListener);
            diskGrid[row][col] = disk;
            add(disk);
         }
      }
   }

   private Icon createIcons(Color color) {
      int width = DISK_WIDTH + 2 * DISK_BORDER_WIDTH;
      BufferedImage bImg = new BufferedImage(width, width, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
      Graphics2D g2 = bImg.createGraphics();
      g2.setColor(color);
      g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
      int x = DISK_BORDER_WIDTH;
      int oWidth = DISK_WIDTH;
      g2.fillOval(x, x, oWidth, oWidth);
      g2.dispose();
      return new ImageIcon(bImg);
   }

   private class DiskListener extends MouseAdapter {
      @Override
      public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
         JLabel disk = (JLabel) e.getSource();
         int selectedColumn = -1;
         for (int row = 0; row < diskGrid.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < diskGrid[row].length; col++) {
               if (disk == diskGrid[row][col]) {
                  selectedColumn = col;
               }
            }
         }

         for (int row = ROWS - 1; row >= 0; row--) {
            if (diskGrid[row][selectedColumn].getIcon() == emptyIcon) {
               Icon icon = firstTurn ? firstIcon : secondIcon;
               diskGrid[row][selectedColumn].setIcon(icon);
               firstTurn = !firstTurn;
               break;
            }
         }

         // TODO check for win
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      Connect4Panel mainPanel = new Connect4Panel();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Connect 4 Panel");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);

      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Click on panel to see how it works!");
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do `Boton3.addActionListener(new Disenos());`