# Boton61.setBackground(Color.red);; changing button background colors

Tags: java

i got a problem with the following code, i am trying to make the button work so when i press it it changes the Button61 background color from white to red, but when i press the button it gives me the following error:

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at proyecto.Diseños.actionPerformed(Diseños.java:367)

Anyone knows how to solve this issue ?

The line 367 is Boton61.setBackground(Color.red);

```
package proyecto;


import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;



/**
 *
 * @author Cristian
 *
 * */

public class Diseños extends JComponent implements ActionListener {

   JButton Boton1, Boton2, Boton3, Boton4, Boton5, Boton6, Boton7;

   JButton Boton11,Boton21,Boton31,Boton41,Boton51,Boton61;
   JButton Boton12,Boton22,Boton32,Boton42,Boton52,Boton62;
   JButton Boton13,Boton23,Boton33,Boton43,Boton53,Boton63;
   JButton Boton14,Boton24,Boton34,Boton44,Boton54,Boton64;
   JButton Boton15,Boton25,Boton35,Boton45,Boton55,Boton65;
   JButton Boton16,Boton26,Boton36,Boton46,Boton56,Boton66;
   JButton Boton17,Boton27,Boton37,Boton47,Boton57,Boton67;




   @Override
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {    

    Boton1=new JButton("lol"); 
    Boton1.setBounds(90, 410, 30, 30); 
    Boton1.setBackground(Color.black);
    Component agregar1 = add(Boton1);
    Boton1.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton2=new JButton("lol"); 
    Boton2.setBounds(150, 410, 30, 30); 
    Boton2.setBackground(Color.black);
    Component agregar2 = add(Boton2);
    Boton2.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton3=new JButton("lol"); 
    Boton3.setBounds(210, 410, 30, 30); 
    Boton3.setBackground(Color.black);
    Component agregar3 = add(Boton3);
    Boton3.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton4=new JButton("lol"); 
    Boton4.setBounds(270, 410, 30, 30); 
    Boton4.setBackground(Color.black);
    Component agregar4 = add(Boton4);
    Boton4.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton5=new JButton("lol"); 
    Boton5.setBounds(330, 410, 30, 30); 
    Boton5.setBackground(Color.black);
    Component agregar5 = add(Boton5);
    Boton5.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton6=new JButton("lol"); 
    Boton6.setBounds(390, 410, 30, 30); 
    Boton6.setBackground(Color.black);
    Component agregar6 = add(Boton6);
    Boton6.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton7=new JButton("lol"); 
    Boton7.setBounds(450, 410, 30, 30); 
    Boton7.setBackground(Color.black);
    Component agregar7 = add(Boton7);
    Boton7.addActionListener(new Diseños());


    Boton11=new JButton(""); 
    Boton11.setBounds(85, 10, 40, 60); 
    Boton11.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar11 = add(Boton11);
    Boton11.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton21=new JButton(""); 
    Boton21.setBounds(85, 70, 40, 60); 
    Boton21.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar21 = add(Boton21);
    Boton21.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton31=new JButton(""); 
    Boton31.setBounds(85, 130, 40, 60); 
    Boton31.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar31 = add(Boton31);
    Boton31.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton41=new JButton(""); 
    Boton41.setBounds(85, 190, 40, 60); 
    Boton41.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar41 = add(Boton41);
    Boton41.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton51=new JButton(""); 
    Boton51.setBounds(85, 250, 40, 60); 
    Boton51.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar51 = add(Boton51);
    Boton51.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton61=new JButton(""); 
    Boton61.setBounds(85, 310, 40, 60); 
    Boton61.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar61 = add(Boton61);
    Boton61.addActionListener(new Diseños());


    Boton12=new JButton(""); 
    Boton12.setBounds(145, 10, 40, 60); 
    Boton12.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar12 = add(Boton12);
    Boton12.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton22=new JButton(""); 
    Boton22.setBounds(145, 70, 40, 60); 
    Boton22.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar22 = add(Boton22);
    Boton22.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton32=new JButton(""); 
    Boton32.setBounds(145, 130, 40, 60); 
    Boton32.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar32 = add(Boton32);
    Boton32.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton42=new JButton(""); 
    Boton42.setBounds(145, 190, 40, 60); 
    Boton42.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar42 = add(Boton42);
    Boton42.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton52=new JButton(""); 
    Boton52.setBounds(145, 250, 40, 60); 
    Boton52.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar52 = add(Boton52);
    Boton52.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton62=new JButton(""); 
    Boton62.setBounds(145, 310, 40, 60); 
    Boton62.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar62 = add(Boton62);
    Boton62.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton13=new JButton(""); 
    Boton13.setBounds(205, 10, 40, 60); 
    Boton13.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar13 = add(Boton13);
    Boton13.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton23=new JButton(""); 
    Boton23.setBounds(205, 70, 40, 60); 
    Boton23.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar23 = add(Boton23);
    Boton23.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton33=new JButton(""); 
    Boton33.setBounds(205, 130, 40, 60); 
    Boton33.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar33 = add(Boton33);
    Boton33.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton43=new JButton(""); 
    Boton43.setBounds(205, 190, 40, 60); 
    Boton43.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar43 = add(Boton43);
    Boton43.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton53=new JButton(""); 
    Boton53.setBounds(205, 250, 40, 60); 
    Boton53.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar53 = add(Boton53);
    Boton53.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton63=new JButton(""); 
    Boton63.setBounds(205, 310, 40, 60); 
    Boton63.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar63 = add(Boton63);
    Boton63.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton14=new JButton(""); 
    Boton14.setBounds(265, 10, 40, 60); 
    Boton14.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar14 = add(Boton14);
    Boton14.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton24=new JButton(""); 
    Boton24.setBounds(265, 70, 40, 60); 
    Boton24.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar24 = add(Boton24);
    Boton24.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton34=new JButton(""); 
    Boton34.setBounds(265, 130, 40, 60); 
    Boton34.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar34 = add(Boton34);
    Boton34.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton44=new JButton(""); 
    Boton44.setBounds(265, 190, 40, 60); 
    Boton44.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar44 = add(Boton44);
    Boton44.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton54=new JButton(""); 
    Boton54.setBounds(265, 250, 40, 60); 
    Boton54.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar54 = add(Boton54);
    Boton54.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton64=new JButton(""); 
    Boton64.setBounds(265, 310, 40, 60); 
    Boton64.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar64 = add(Boton64);
    Boton64.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton15=new JButton(""); 
    Boton15.setBounds(325, 10, 40, 60); 
    Boton15.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar15 = add(Boton15);
    Boton15.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton25=new JButton(""); 
    Boton25.setBounds(325, 70, 40, 60); 
    Boton25.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar25 = add(Boton25);
    Boton25.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton35=new JButton(""); 
    Boton35.setBounds(325, 130, 40, 60); 
    Boton35.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar35 = add(Boton35);
    Boton35.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton45=new JButton(""); 
    Boton45.setBounds(325, 190, 40, 60); 
    Boton45.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar45 = add(Boton45);
    Boton45.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton55=new JButton(""); 
    Boton55.setBounds(325, 250, 40, 60); 
    Boton55.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar55 = add(Boton55);
    Boton55.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton65=new JButton(""); 
    Boton65.setBounds(325, 310, 40, 60); 
    Boton65.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar65 = add(Boton65);
    Boton65.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton16=new JButton(""); 
    Boton16.setBounds(385, 10, 40, 60); 
    Boton16.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar16 = add(Boton16);
    Boton16.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton26=new JButton(""); 
    Boton26.setBounds(385, 70, 40, 60); 
    Boton26.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar26 = add(Boton26);
    Boton26.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton36=new JButton(""); 
    Boton36.setBounds(385, 130, 40, 60); 
    Boton36.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar36 = add(Boton36);
    Boton36.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton46=new JButton(""); 
    Boton46.setBounds(385, 190, 40, 60); 
    Boton46.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar46 = add(Boton46);
    Boton46.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton56=new JButton(""); 
    Boton56.setBounds(385, 250, 40, 60); 
    Boton56.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar56 = add(Boton56);
    Boton56.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton66=new JButton(""); 
    Boton66.setBounds(385, 310, 40, 60); 
    Boton66.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar66 = add(Boton66);
    Boton66.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton17=new JButton(""); 
    Boton17.setBounds(445, 10, 40, 60); 
    Boton17.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar17 = add(Boton17);
    Boton17.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton27=new JButton(""); 
    Boton27.setBounds(445, 70, 40, 60); 
    Boton27.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar27 = add(Boton27);
    Boton27.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton37=new JButton(""); 
    Boton37.setBounds(445, 130, 40, 60); 
    Boton37.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar37 = add(Boton37);
    Boton37.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton47=new JButton(""); 
    Boton47.setBounds(445, 190, 40, 60); 
    Boton47.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar47 = add(Boton47);
    Boton47.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton57=new JButton(""); 
    Boton57.setBounds(445, 250, 40, 60); 
    Boton57.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar57 = add(Boton57);
    Boton57.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    Boton67=new JButton(""); 
    Boton67.setBounds(445, 310, 40, 60); 
    Boton67.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar67 = add(Boton67);
    Boton67.addActionListener(new Diseños());

    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawRect (570, 10, 300, 200);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(570, 10, 300, 200);
    g.drawRect (570, 250, 300, 200);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(570, 250, 300, 200);
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    Font oldFont=getFont();
    Font fuente=new Font("Primer Jugador", Font.BOLD, 14);
    g.setFont(fuente);
    g.drawString("Primer Jugador", 580, 30);
    Font titulo=new Font("Segundo Jugador", Font.BOLD, 14);
    g.setFont(titulo);
    g.drawString("Segundo Jugador", 580, 270);
    g.drawString("[ " + Proyecto.primernombre + " ]", 580, 50);
    g.drawString("[ " + Proyecto.segundonombre + " ]", 580, 290);
    g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
    g.fillRoundRect(10, 5, 550, 450, 50, 50);



  }

   @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        System.out.println("Ayy lmao");
        Boton61.setBackground(Color.red);;


    }

}
```

Comment: None of the button component creation code should be in paintComponent. This was discussed in your last question. Put your component creation code within the class's constructor. The paintComponent method should be for painting and painting only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. None of the button component creation code should be in paintComponent. This was well discussed (I thought) in my answer to [your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28143599/why-the-actionlistener-does-not-work). Put your component creation code within the class's constructor. The paintComponent method should be for painting and painting only.
2. You're using the class as an ActionListener which is sort of OK for toy programs, but if you do that, don't create a new Disenos object, but rather use `this`. This is the reason for your NullPointerException since the JButtons in the newly created Disenos ActionListeners are never created since the class is never "painted", never displayed. To be clear, you're creating almost 100 Disenos objects, but only one of them is being displayed.
3. Myself, I much prefer to avoid having my view classes implement my listener interfaces as it puts too much responsibility on the view class.
4. Also if you use arrays and for loops, your code could be shortened **considerably**.

---

For example:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Disenos2 extends JPanel {
   public static final int ROWS = 6;
   public static final int COLUMNS = 7;

   private JButton[][] botones = new JButton[ROWS][COLUMNS];
   private boolean redTurn = true;

   public Disenos2() {
      ButtonAction buttonAction = new ButtonAction();
      setLayout(new GridLayout(ROWS, COLUMNS, 5, 5));
      for (int row = 0; row < botones.length; row++) {
         for (int col = 0; col < botones[row].length; col++) {
            JButton boton = new JButton("      ");
            boton.addActionListener(buttonAction);
            add(boton);
            botones[row][col] = boton;
         }
      }
   }

   private class ButtonAction implements ActionListener {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         JButton boton = (JButton) e.getSource();
         int column = -1;
         for (int row = 0; row < botones.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < botones[row].length; col++) {
               if (boton == botones[row][col]) {
                  column = col;
               }
            }
         }

         for (int row = ROWS - 1; row >= 0; row--) {
            Color bkgd = botones[row][column].getBackground();
            if (!isColorSelected(botones[row][column])) {
               Color c = redTurn ? Color.red : Color.black;
               botones[row][column].setBackground(c);
               redTurn = !redTurn;
               break;
            }
         }
      }

      private boolean isColorSelected(JButton jButton) {
         Color c = jButton.getBackground();
         if (Color.red.equals(c)) {
            return true;
         }
         if (Color.black.equals(c)) {
            return true;
         }
         return false;
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      Disenos2 mainPanel = new Disenos2();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Disenos2");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }

}
```

Comment: I know how to use array and for loops, thanks for all your help, also your advice did help me fix the color change, sorry for the inconvenience but i am a novice, can you give me a small example of what you mean with locating the buttons towards the class's constructor?

Comment: @CristianGonzalez: for example

Comment: Thanks alot, you cleared all my doubts and now my program fully works.